# How to get a better initial guess for the nth root approximation?

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C that uses approximation to calculate the nth root of a number. Everything works but, with this approach you need an assumption for the guess and I would like to improve this assumption but I don't know how.

So this down below is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
float power(float num, int t){
    for(float n = num; t > 1; t--){
        num*=n;
    }
    return(num);
}
int main(){
    float num, nthroot, guess, numpower, numpowerless, error, iterations = 20;
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);
    printf("Nthroot: ");
    scanf("%f", &nthroot);
    guess = num/nthroot;
    for(int c; c < iterations; c++){
        numpower=power(guess, nthroot);
        numpowerless=power(guess, nthroot-1);
        error=(num-numpower)/(nthroot*numpowerless);
        guess+=error;
    }
    printf("The %f root of %f is %f\n.", nthroot, num, guess+error);
}
```

And to make this code run faster I would love to reduce the variable iterations to like 2 or 3 but if I do that, then I would lose precision. So I need a better guess than just num/nthroot. The guess should be as near as possible to the result, but I don't know how to do it. Help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Please take notice of the compiler warnings given. Deal with them before looking at efficiency. Moreover, please work with `double`. Never use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C.

Comment: You might do better by terminating the approximation when the estimate doesn't change by more than an epsilon value, and then compare the number of iterations for different initial estimates.

Comment: You may need some variant of [Carmack hack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Comment: 65535 is 16 bits. Floor of the square root of 65535 is 255 which 8 bits. Floor of the cube root of 65535 is 40 which is 5.3 bits. Floor of the fourth root of 65535 is 15 which is 4 bits. So if you count the number of bits in the original number, and divide by `n`, you'll get a reasonable estimate of the number of bits in the answer.

Comment: Your power function only calculates non-negative whole number powers. It takes an int as argument, but you're calling it with a float. I suggest you get the program to work correctly, then optimise for speed.

Comment: The initial guess is not the most obvious place to focus for efficiency. Should this algorithm assume that `n` is an integer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. user3386109 I have improved my code by implementing something like your suggestion. And Simon Goater the powerfuntion only needs to return positive values. And in main I store the Nthroot as a float because otherwise it could mess something up in the error calculation and I only need to call it in the powerfunktion as a int because I use it for iterating. To your suggestion of getting my program to work correctly, I can only tell u I does what it should do correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the question, the goal is to calculate the `n`th root of a positive number `num` using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for calculating successively better approximations in an iterative process.

It is assumed that `n` is an integer larger than 1 and `num` is a positive floating-point number represented as a `double`.

**Initial guess**

A good initial guess can reduce the number of iterations needed to reach a desired accuracy. However, as each iteration is not very costly, the calculation of the initial guess should also not be costly. Furthermore, since the estimate converges quickly when getting close to the result, it is more important to stop the iterations when the estimate is acceptable (see below).

Anyway, assuming that the integer part of `num` can be represented by an integer type, e.g. `uint64_t`, the following method can be used:

First, notice that if `r` is the nth root of `x`, then

```
r^n = x  =>
n * log2(r) = log2(x)  =>
r = 2^(log2(x)/n)
```

So in very rough terms, the root can be estimated by shifting a bit to the position which is "the position of the most significant bit of `x`" divided by `n`. This can be done efficiently as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t rootEstimate(uint64_t x, unsigned n)
{
    uint64_t result = 1;
    while(x = x >> n)
    {
        result = result << 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Iterations**

Instead of running a fixed number of iterations, the process should be stopped when the change in the approximated value is less than some defined `tolerance`.

Furthermore, the formula (with `x`=`num`, `x_k`=`estimate` and `n`=`nthroot` for readability):

```
   x_{k+1} = x_k + (x - (x_k)^n)/(n*(x_k)^(n-1))
```

[can be rearranged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Computing_principal_roots) as follows:

```
   x_{k+1} = (n-1)/n * x_k + (x/n) * (1 / (x_k)^(n-1))
```

Notice that `(n-1)/n` and `x/n` are fixed constants which can be pre-calculated outside the iterative loop and that this formula only requires one exponentiation.

All in all, this can be implemented as follows:

```
double power(double x, unsigned n)
{
    double x0 = x;
    while(n-->1)  // Run "n-1" iterations
    {
        x *= x0;
    }
    return x;
}

#define abs(x) (((x) > 0) ? (x) : -(x))

int main(void)
{
    double num, estimate, tolerance = 1e-10, estimatePrev;
    unsigned nthroot;
    printf("Number: ");
    if(scanf("%lf", &num) != 1 || num < 0.0)
    {
        printf("Error: Must be a non-negative floating-point number\n");
        return 1;  
    }
    printf("Nthroot: ");
    if(scanf("%u", &nthroot) != 1 || nthroot < 2)
    {
        printf("Error: Must be an integer larger than 1\n");
        return 1;  
    }

    double mult1 = (double)(nthroot - 1) / (double)nthroot;
    double mult2 = num / (double)nthroot;
    estimate = rootEstimate((uint64_t)num, nthroot);  // printf("guess = %f\n", estimate);
    do
    {
        estimatePrev = estimate;
        estimate = mult1 * estimate + mult2 / power(estimate, nthroot - 1);
    } while(abs(estimate - estimatePrev) > tolerance);
    printf("The %u root of %f is %.9f\n", nthroot, num, estimate);
}
```